# Convert an fstab entry to a systemd mount unit on CoreOS

Tags: systemd, coreos

I want to convert the following fstab entry to a systemd mount unit on CoreOS,

`/dev/xvdb /data ext4 defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0`

I created `data.mount`,

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Data Directory

[Mount]
What=/dev/xvdb
Where=/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,auto,noatime,noexec 0 0
```

However, I had to remove `0 0` because the unit failed to start.

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Data Directory

[Mount]
What=/dev/xvdb
Where=/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,auto,noatime,noexec
```

The unit above starts, but I'm not sure about the `Options=` string. Reading about the `fstab` options I wonder if some are redundant.

According to [Ubuntu Fstab - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

> auto - The filesystem can be mounted automatically (at bootup, or when
>   mount is passed the -a option). This is really unnecessary as this is
>   the default action of mount -a anyway.
>
> defaults - Use default settings. Equivalent to rw, suid, dev, exec,
>   auto, nouser, async.

This leads me to the following unit,

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Data Directory

[Mount]
What=/dev/xvdb
Where=/data
Type=ext4
Options=defaults,noatime,noexec
```

Is this the proper way to create a mount unit using systemd on CoreOS?

Answer (score 3):

`defaults` is redundant. When any other options are in use, it can be omitted. It only exists to fill the relevant column in `fstab`.

And since `auto` is already a default, it too is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the proper way to create a mount unit using systemd.